# Django DecimalField min value validation error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I need a decimal field in my form with a minimal value of 0.20, maximal value of 20 with 2 decimal places as you can see in the code bellow.

```
forms.DecimalField(min_value=0.20, max_value=20.00, max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, initial=1)
```

The problem occures when you put 0.20 in, because you get a validation error:

**Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 0.20.**


I'm using *python 3.10* and *Django 4.0.4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own custom validator also make sure you take min / max values from configurations / settings file instead of hardcoding .

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/custom-field-validations-in-django-models/

Answer (score 1):

use Decimal for min_value or max_value:

```py
forms.DecimalField(min_value=Decimal('0.20'), max_value=Decimal('20.00'), max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, initial=1)
```